# Response.Redirect error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have form page that collects data.  The user clicks SUBMIT, which goes to a "post page.  At the end of this page is the redirect code I am using.
    `response.redirect( "test.asp?ChecklistID=" + ChecklistID )`
For some reason, the result is this.

> /test.asp?ChecklistID=4784,%204784

Why is this returning in TWO ID's?  I only have ONE record in the 'results' table.  And it is '4784'.

Adding the code

```
<%
'Option Explicit
Dim SQLStmt, sql, RS, ChecklistID, Location, ChecklistDate, Driveup, 
ConnectString, conn, objconn
Dim weeds, parking_lot, sidewalk, windows, exterior_trash, door_clean
Dim mats_clean, Notes_page1

Location = Request("Location")
ChecklistDate = Request("ChecklistDate")
Driveup = Request("Driveup")
ChecklistID = Request("ChecklistID")
weeds = Request("weeds")
parking_lot = Request("parking_lot")
sidewalk = Request("sidewalk")
windows = Request("windows")
exterior_trash = Request("exterior_trash")
door_clean = Request("door_clean")
mats_clean = Request("mats_clean")
Notes_page1 = Request("Notes_page1")

ConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & 
Server.MapPath("../xyz/mydatabase.mdb")
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open ConnectString

SQLStmt = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE ChecklistID =" & ChecklistID & " ; "

Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

RS.open "Results", conn, 3, 3
RS.Update
RS("ChecklistDate") = ChecklistDate
RS("Driveup") = Driveup
RS("weeds") = weeds
RS("parking_lot") = parking_lot
RS("sidewalk") = sidewalk
RS("windows") = windows
RS("exterior_trash") = exterior_trash
RS("door_clean") = door_clean
RS("mats_clean") = mats_clean
RS("Notes_page1") = Notes_page1
RS.Update

RS.close
set RS = nothing
conn.close
set conn = nothing  

response.redirect( "test.asp?ChecklistID=" + ChecklistID )

%>
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code?

Comment: Result is in fact one id 2 times - what you see is escaped `ChecklistID=4784, 4784` (Please note space after comma - it is %20 after escaping). Did you inspect variable ChecklistID? Is it string? Maybe somwhere else in code you are adding something 2 times?

Comment: Adding the code

Comment: The code is added.  I am puzzled ! !

Answer (score 0):

The browser might be retaining some history with response.redirect. Try using Server.Transfer. Or, if it's the same page, you might not have to re-add the query string.

Comment: I have never had a problem with a browser retaining history using this response.redirect code.  I am at a loss.

Comment: Fwiw: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Solved
I had the same hidden field in there twice causing the issue.